# Pygame doesn't detect it when i press right, up, and left at the same time

Tags: python, pygame

Try it yourself, here's a simple code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


SCREEN_WIDTH = 400
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

loop = True
while loop:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    if len(events) > 0:
        print(events)
    for event in events:

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = False
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

You'll see that if you press and hold the buttons LEFT, UP, and RIGHT (in that order), the RIGHT keypress isn't registered in the event tracker, making it impossible to detect. This has to be a bug with pygame, right? Try to combine a few other button presses, you'll see some weird behavior with some keys that just won't register if they're pressed in a certain order (only happens when a key is held down though)

Comment: Pretty sure this is not a problem in pygame, but with your keyboard.

Comment: I asked someone else, and it seems to be something called keyboard ghosting. Is there a smart alternate way to register a third keypress after two arrowkeys have been pressed down?

Comment: Buying a gamer keyboard with n-key rollover is your best bet. This is a hardware issue.

Comment: i know, but the fact is that most of the people i'm going to be making this program for, have the same issues as me. That means that i have to find an alternate way to make this work if i want the program to be accessible.

Comment: I'd suggest using other keys on the keyboard. The use-case for pressing left, up and right at the same time is pretty far from normal typing, but maybe pressing w, a and d at the same time works better, so try wasd?

Comment: This is a hardware limitation of the keyboard you're using. See here for an explanation: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20449/keyboard-multiple-key-press-problem